# Failed to build a naive project using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have failed to build a naive project using Visual Studio 2015.

It's a matter of environment which is still not fixed.

I am using Windows 10 Education, using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.

Thank you so much for your help.

```
Error   TRK0005 Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified.  myproj  D:\Documents\XXX    1
```

Comment: Repair your Visual Studio installation. Don't forget to tick C++ Dev Tools checkbox (C++ tools are not being installed by default anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to use the *Custom Install* rather than *Typical Install* when installing Visual Studio 2015 if you want C/C++ tools.

As you have already installed it go to the control panel, select *Programs and Features*, select "Microsoft Visual Studio Education 2015", hit the *Change* Button. When the Visual Studio dialog comes up, select *Modify*. Then select the checkbox next to "Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015" under Programming Languages -> Visual C++ and hit *Update*.

[image]

> This requires administrator rights.

See [Visual C++ Team Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/24/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Just occurred for me migrating a native project to Visual Studio 2017.
In my case it was caused by the project referencing an obsolete Platform ToolSet via a property sheet. In my case, an old Windows 8.1 SDK property sheet.

Use Property Manager to check your projects for old property sheets. Even if you choose to upgrade the project, the project settings may be silently overridden.